# VLOOKUP not populating cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am new to the VLOOKUP function. What I am attempting to do is pull over a value from the "CL Planning" sheet if its "Status" value equals "Active". My attempt has been unsuccessful so far.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is the formula I am using. It is found on the "Emails | Popups & Invites" tab.

`=VLOOKUP(Key!$C$5,'CL Planning'!C10:G10,1,FALSE)`

Here are the sheets that I reference:

[image]

The key sheet is being used to house the value I am trying to find. Which is "Active".

[image]

Then on the "CL Planning" sheet, I am attempting to find a row with a "Status" of "Active". Once found, I am wanting to pull over the "Community", so in this case, "Stonebridge Towns".

[image]

Below is the actual sheet that the results would populate on and that contains my formula.

[image]

UPDATE -----------------

If I have the following data below. The yellow part is not pulled from any other sheet. This column would be notes entered that do not derive from a lookup elsewhere. It is manually entered.

What I am trying to figure out is if "Stonebridge" is removed from the referenced sheet, that the notes are removed with it, so that when the row containing "Community A" information moves up, the notes remain with it, rather than the second photo below (the notes sliding up, not being correlated with the correct record).

[image]

Stonebridge removed and notes staying where they were before.

[image]

Comment: You can only return the content of columns to the right of the column you lookup. Use `INDEX/MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Ayte, index,match, or xlookup. But not if you want to vlookup then the key needs to be the most leftmosts, and I am confused by the hard cell reference $c$5.  I would have expected C9, or C10 etc etc. And the rest of the data to the right.

Comment: @Hennes the absolute reference was for the Status of "Available" on the Key tab. That shouldn't change and is why I made it absolute.

Comment: Suggest you have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1 to understand (i) why your `VLOOKUP` is returning `#N/A` and (ii) why it is the wrong function to be using in the example you have provided.

Comment: Note VLOOKUP will only return one "active" row. I assume you want to copy all community fields for which status is ACTIVE. Why not just use the filter and select all active? If you need the list of communitities on a seperate sheets (and have office 365) have a look at the FILTER(...) function which can return the list of active communitities as a dynamic array (only supported in O365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you could have a check.

`=VLOOKUP(Key!$C$5,IF({1,0},'CL Planning'!G10:G11,'CL Planning'!C10:C11),2,FALSE)`

Please note, this is an array formula, so you need to press Ctrl +Shift + Enter keys at the same time. Vlookup supports vertical query, so the query area is the range according to the column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I would have to do that for each cell to pull the value then, right? Side question. Let's say I add a column after "Sales" (using your illustration as a reference. This new called could be called notes. It would be manually typed in (not referenced from anywhere else. How do I get that notes cell for Stonebriidge to stay associated with Stonebridge with other community names being added in?

Comment: @user1530279  As the orders of title cells are different on two sheets, so you need to use different formulas with specific ranges for these title values.

Comment: @user1530279  For the association between notes and the Community Name, could you please provide more information? Such as give me a simple sample.

Comment: see the updated question with an example and more indepth explaination.

Comment: @user1530279  Thanks for your details. In my opinion, this requirement is a new question, and it needs VBA code help. I would suggest you post a new thread to seek assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A number of thoughts here. The limited information means I'm not sure just which would be of interest to you, so apply as you find useful.

First, `VLOOKUP()` actually CAN "look left" no matter what everyone says. More on that later. However, it is not as straightforward as the nice (new) `XLOOKUP()`. So you would have an easier life just using `XLOOKUP()` instead. But, if you prefer `VLOOKUP()` for whatever reason (personal preference, die-hard love of it, or more practically, you have users with older versions of Excel and need something that will work with them, then use it.

If no preference, and you need something for older versions, `INDEX/MATCH` is fairly easy to understand and use. In fact, `XLOOKUP()` simply places its functional parts "under the hood" and works largely the same. Used for decades, so you can use it sure that it will work as intended.

However, you are looking up something that is basically TRUE/FALSE and looking like you are planning on doing it for many results, not just one. That means `FILTER()` is the formula for you, so long as you do not have users with older versions. It returns however many items meet the criteria. It also has the nice feature that you can use the column of information you want results from in its first parameter, and some entirely different column for the criteria test. So you only get the result you want, not a row of information that has lots of non-useful material.

For older user support, well, there are ways you can find to return results from multiple rows, but they are a bit arcane.

So, how can you use `VLOOKUP()` to "look left?" By creating your lookup table in a helpful way. "Creating your lookup table?" Don't you just specify a range that rectangles off the relevant material? No. You DO figure out the rectangle to use, but you then use `INDEX()` on that range instead of just typing in the range address.

`INDEX()` lets you specify the columns you want to use. Quite a few ways to do that, but the one you want is called an "array constant." If you had five columns and used an array constant, the parameter would look like this to get them all, and in order:  `{1,2,3,4,5}`. But... they don't have to be in order. (Nor do they have to all be used, and they can be used however many times you like. You want a last name (say, column 3) to appear four times in your output? Perhaps in this order:  `{1,3,8,9,10,3,2,6,4,3,11,23}`? Not a problem!)

So, say you have a raw range of A1:H100. Your lookup column is F and your result column is B. You have a formula, `SEQUENCE()` that gives the rows to return (there's a version using `ROW(1:xxx)` for older Excel versions. Then the following would do the trick:

```
=VLOOKUP(K1,  INDEX($A$1:$H$100,SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($A$1:$H$100)),{6,2}),  1,FALSE)
```

You are making an internal (virtual) table and placing column F first, then column B. So `VLOOKUP()` is given a "look right" table from "look left" real world data and works nicely.

So yes, call it `VLOOKUP/INDEX` and consider it a red-headed stepchild... some do, or sneer outright. But `INDEX/MATCH` is a double function neither of whom's parts do the job by themselves so... Mostly though, it looks like you want `FILTER()`.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. The xlookup and filter function doesn't look to be available for my Excel version. So I tried using the vlookup with index. I cannot get it to work. The extended formula is throwing me off and I'm honestly not sure what half of it is doing.